# For a large validation task is chain of responsibility pattern a good bet?

Tags: java, design-patterns, chain-of-responsibility

I need to build a process which will validate a record against ~200 validation rules.  A record can be one of ~10 types.  There is some segmentation from validation rules to record types but there exists a lot of overlap which prevents me from cleanly binning the validation rules.

During my design I'm considering a chain of responsibility pattern for all of the validation rules.  Is this a good idea or is there a better design pattern?

Comment: It's definitely not a bad bet. Were you thinking of creating separate chains for each type, or a single chain for all types?

Comment: A single chain for all types (because the rules don't segment well) but test if it applies to the record.  I was thinking this would make the addition of new rules easier too.  (Read: easier for client to understand...)

Comment: Have you considered using Drools?

Answer (score 21):

Validation is frequently a Composite pattern. When you break it down, you want to seperate the  *what* you want to from the *how* you want to do it, you get:

If foo is valid
then do something.

Here we have the abstraction *is valid*  -- Caveat: This code was lifted from currrent, similar examples so you may find missing symbology and such. But this is so you get the picture. In addition, the

```
Result
```

Object contains messaging about the failure as well as a simple status (true/false).
This allow you the option of just asking "did it pass?" vs. "If it failed, tell me why"

```
QuickCollection
```

and

```
QuickMap
```

Are convenience classes for taking any class and quickly turning them into those respected types by merely assigning to a delegate. For this example it means your composite validator is already a collection and can be iterated, for example.

You had a secondary problem in your question: "cleanly binding" as in, "Type A" -> rules{a,b,c}" and "Type B" -> rules{c,e,z}"

This is easily managed with a Map. Not entirely a [Command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) but close

```
Map<Type,Validator> typeValidators = new HashMap<>();
```

Setup the validator for each type then create a mapping between types. This is really best done as bean config if you're using Java but **Definitely** use [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)

```
    public interface Validator<T>{
    
    
        public Result validate(T value);
    
    
        public static interface Result {
    
            public static final Result OK = new Result() {
                @Override
                public String getMessage() {
                    return "OK";
                }
    
                @Override
                public String toString() {
                    return "OK";
                }
    
                @Override
                public boolean isOk() {
                    return true;
                }
            };
    
            public boolean isOk();
    
            public String getMessage();
        }
    }
```

Now some simple implementations to show the point:

```
public class MinLengthValidator implements Validator<String> {
    
    private final SimpleResult FAILED;
    
    private Integer minLength;
    
    public MinLengthValidator() {
        this(8);
    }
    
    public MinLengthValidator(Integer minLength) {
        this.minLength = minLength;
        FAILED = new SimpleResult("Password must be at least "+minLength+" characters",false);
    }
    
    @Override
    public Result validate(String newPassword) {
        return newPassword.length() >= minLength ? Result.OK : FAILED;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.getClass().getSimpleName();
    }
}
```

Here is another we will combine with

```
    public class NotCurrentValidator implements Validator<String> {
    
        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("userPasswordEncoder")
        private PasswordEncoder encoder;
    
        private static final SimpleResult FAILED = new SimpleResult("Password cannot be your current password",false);
    
        @Override
        public Result validate(String newPassword) {
            boolean passed = !encoder.matches(newPassword,user.getPassword());
            return (passed ? Result.OK : FAILED);
        }
    
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return this.getClass().getSimpleName();
        }
    
    }
```

Now here is a composite:

```
public class CompositePasswordRule extends QuickCollection<Validator> implements Validator<String> {


public CompositeValidator(Collection<Validator> rules) {
    super.delegate = rules;
}

public CompositeValidator(Validator<?>... rules) {
    super.delegate = Arrays.asList(rules);
}



@Override
public CompositeResult validate(String newPassword) {
    CompositeResult result = new CompositeResult(super.delegate.size());
    for(Validator rule : super.delegate){
        Result temp = rule.validate(newPassword);
        if(!temp.isOk())
            result.put(rule,temp);
    }

    return result;
}


    public static class CompositeResult extends QuickMap<Validator,Result> implements Result {
        private Integer appliedCount;

        private CompositeResult(Integer appliedCount) {
            super.delegate = VdcCollections.delimitedMap(new HashMap<PasswordRule, Result>(), "-->",", ");
            this.appliedCount = appliedCount;
        }

        @Override
        public String getMessage() {
            return super.delegate.toString();
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return super.delegate.toString();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isOk() {
            boolean isOk = true;
            for (Result r : delegate.values()) {
                isOk = r.isOk();
                if(!isOk)
                    break;
            }
            return isOk;
        }
        public Integer failCount() {
            return this.size();
        }

        public Integer passCount() {
            return appliedCount - this.size();
        }
    }
}
```

and now a snippet of use:

```
private Validator<String> pwRule = new CompositeValidator<String>(new MinLengthValidator(),new NotCurrentValidator());

Validator.Result result = pwRule.validate(newPassword);
if(!result.isOk())
    throw new PasswordConstraintException("%s", result.getMessage());

user.obsoleteCurrentPassword();
user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(newPassword));
user.setPwExpDate(DateTime.now().plusDays(passwordDaysToLive).toDate());
userDao.updateUser(user);
```

Comment: Neat! Can I make a gist out of it?

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/JExaples/quicklooks/tree/master/Chain-of-Responsibility) you go, buddy. Are you planning to continue development on it? I had similar issue today and I thought that I should give it a go and make a library or something that I can use in my later projects.

Answer (score 5):

Chain of responsibility implies that there is an order in which the validations must take place.  I would probably use something similar to the Strategy pattern where you have a Set of validation strategies that are applied to a specific type of record.  You could then use a factory to examine the record and apply the correct set of validations.

Comment: CoR does allow ordering of dependencies, but it's in no way required in order to use the pattern.

Comment: Thus the word "implies".  This is essentially an opinion-based question.  I gave my opinion.