# Template method pattern with different implemented method parameters

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns

I'm implementing the template method pattern and in my abstract class I have a method(`TemplateMethod`) that gets some values and passes them to `Step2` method.

The conflict I have is that my two concrete implementations use just a partial set of these parameters so I don't like the idea of passing all parameters and I wouldn't want to modify this method signature if another concrete implementation would require different parameters.

I have read about [Parameter Object](https://refactoring.com/catalog/introduceParameterObject.html) pattern and saw [another very similar question in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23503932/template-method-pattern-where-each-implementation-requires-different-arguments#) but I'm still not convinced. Any suggestions?

Here is my simplified code:

```
void Main()
{
    var concreteClassA = new ConcreteClassA();
    concreteClassA.TemplateMethod();
    var concreteClassB = new ConcreteClassB();
    concreteClassB.TemplateMethod();
}

public abstract class AbstractClass
{
    IEngine1 _engine1;
    IEngine2 _engine2;
    public void TemplateMethod() {
        Step1();
        //Get some values
        var id = _engine1.GetId();
        var name = _engine1.GetName();
        var anotherId = _engine2.GetAnotherId();
        var description = _engine2.GetDescription();
        //Pass all values to step 2
        Step2(id, name, anotherId, description);
    }
    public virtual void Step1() { }
    public virtual void Step2(int id, string name, int anotherId, int description) {}
}

public interface IEngine1 { 
    int GetId();
    string GetName();
}
public interface IEngine2
{
    int GetAnotherId();
    int GetDescription();
}

public class ConcreteClassA : AbstractClass
{
    public override void Step2(int id, string name, int anotherId, int description)
    {
        //This class only needs Id and name!
        var entity = new Entity {
            Id = id,
            Name = name
        }
        DoSomethingWithEntity(entity);
    }
    private void DoSomethingWithEntity(Entity entity) {
            //Logic here
    }
}

public class ConcreteClassB : AbstractClass
{
    public override void Step2(int id, string name, int anotherId, int description)
    {
        //This one needs other parameters
        var entity = new Entity
        {
            AnotherId = anotherId,
            Name = name,
            Description = description
        }
        DoSomethingElseWithEntity(entity);
    }
    private void DoSomethingElseWithEntity(Entity entity)
    {
        //Logic here
    }
}

public class Entity { 
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int AnotherId { get; set; }
    public int Description { get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Are you using this pattern because it is the right tool for what you are trying to do, or because you *want* to implement the pattern?

Comment: My original code had a big method with different branches like If type == X then build Entity with params a,b,c. If Type == Y then build entity with params b,c,d. I thought template method pattern would be a good option for this

Comment: Looks like there is no need for `TemplateMethod` because each concrete implementation can get parameters it needs from `engine`s directly.

Comment: It would be great if you could not use `AbstratClass`, `ConcreteClassA`, etc. as opposed to the real names, because it's possible your pattern is another one (Strategy?). When you don't give the details, answers tend to shed more heat than light.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to pass a model. You just let the model be a parameter

When You will be changing parameters will not change the `Step2` method signature.

Just add property in `ParamterContext`

Here is the sample code

```
public class ParameterContext
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int anotherId { get; set; }
    public int description { get; set; }
}


public abstract class AbstractClass
{
    IEngine1 _engine1;
    IEngine2 _engine2;
    public void TemplateMethod()
    {
        Step1();
        //Get some values
        var id = _engine1.GetId();
        var name = _engine1.GetName();
        var anotherId = _engine2.GetAnotherId();
        var description = _engine2.GetDescription();
        //Pass all values to step 2
        Step2(new ParameterContext() {
            id = id,
            name = name,
            anotherId = anotherId,
            description = description
        });
    }
    public virtual void Step1() { }
    public virtual void Step2(ParameterContext parameter) { }
}

public interface IEngine1
{
    int GetId();
    string GetName();
}
public interface IEngine2
{
    int GetAnotherId();
    int GetDescription();
}

public class ConcreteClassA : AbstractClass
{
    public override void Step2(ParameterContext para)
    {
        //This class only needs Id and name!
        var entity = new Entity
        {
            Id = para.id,
            Name = para.name
        };
        DoSomethingWithEntity(entity);
    }
    private void DoSomethingWithEntity(Entity entity)
    {
        //Logic here
    }
}

public class ConcreteClassB : AbstractClass
{
    public override void Step2(ParameterContext para)
    {
        //This one needs other parameters
        var entity = new Entity
        {
            AnotherId = para.anotherId,
            Name = para.name,
            Description = para.description
        };
        DoSomethingElseWithEntity(entity);
    }
    private void DoSomethingElseWithEntity(Entity entity)
    {
        //Logic here
    }
}
```

**Edit**

Another way is

The `IEngine1` and `IEngine2` interface declared as protect which in `AbstractClass` class,You can use their method instead of passing parameter.

```
public abstract class AbstractClass
{
    public AbstractClass() { }

    public AbstractClass(IEngine1 eng1, IEngine2 eng2)
    {
        _engine1 = eng1;
        _engine2 = eng2;
    }

    protected IEngine1 _engine1;
    protected IEngine2 _engine2;
    public void TemplateMethod()
    {
        Step1();
        //Get some values
        //var id = _engine1.GetId();
        //var name = _engine1.GetName();
        //var anotherId = _engine2.GetAnotherId();
        //var description = _engine2.GetDescription();
        //Pass all values to step 2
        Step2();
    }
    public virtual void Step1() { }
    public virtual void Step2() { }
}

public interface IEngine1
{
    int GetId();
    string GetName();
}
public interface IEngine2
{
    int GetAnotherId();
    int GetDescription();
}

public class ConcreteClassA : AbstractClass
{
    public override void Step2()
    {
        //This class only needs Id and name!
        var entity = new Entity
        {
            Id = _engine1.GetId(),
            Name = _engine1.GetName()
        };
        DoSomethingWithEntity(entity);
    }
    private void DoSomethingWithEntity(Entity entity)
    {
        //Logic here
    }
}

public class ConcreteClassB : AbstractClass
{
    public override void Step2()
    {
        //This one needs other parameters
        var entity = new Entity
        {
            AnotherId = _engine2.GetAnotherId(),
            Name = _engine1.GetName(),
            Description = _engine2.GetDescription()
        };
        DoSomethingElseWithEntity(entity);
    }
    private void DoSomethingElseWithEntity(Entity entity)
    {
        //Logic here
    }
}

public class Entity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int AnotherId { get; set; }
    public int Description { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This almost looks like Strategy, since you're passing a context.

Comment: If there are different algorithm on `Step2()` method,that is Strategy pattern.

I just encapsulated parameter as Context,and passing as parameter.

To solve the `Step2()` signature without changing the parameter method