# Java swing Input validation

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have a question about a registration frame. This frame has several fields: name,secondname,password,reapeat password textfield and role  a combobox field . I want to validate the fields and if they are ok i want that a button is enabled and data are sent to a database. I used a keylistener for a the textfield and actionlistener for combobox. I want to do somenthing like this:

```
if( nameField="ok" and secondNameField="ok" and passwordField="ok" and repeatPasswordField ="ok" and roleField="ok" ) then button.setEnabled(true)
```

Is there a pattern i could use?How can I manage input validation?This is what i have done:

```
public class RegisterFormListener implements KeyListener,ActionListener{
private boolean nameVerification=false;
private boolean cognomeVerification=false;
private boolean passwordVerification=false;
private boolean ripPassVerification=false;
private boolean emailVerification = false;
private boolean ruoloVerification=false;
InputVerification registerFormVerification = new InputVerification();
private JPasswordField pass=new JPasswordField();
private JButton save=null;
public RegisterFormListener(JButton btn) {
    save=btn;
    
}

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    
}
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    String field=e.getComponent().getName();
    JTextField inputField=(JTextField)e.getComponent();
    //JPasswordField inputPassField =(JPasswordField)e.getComponent();
    switch(field) {
    case "nome":
        if(registerFormVerification.nameVerification(inputField.getText())) {
            inputField.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            nameVerification=true;
        }else {
            inputField.setBackground(Color.RED);
            nameVerification=false;
        }
        
        break;
    case "cognome":
        if(registerFormVerification.cognomeVerification(inputField.getText())) {
            inputField.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            cognomeVerification=true;
        }else {
            inputField.setBackground(Color.RED);
            cognomeVerification=false;
        }
        break;
    case "email":
        if(registerFormVerification.emailVerification(inputField.getText())) {
            inputField.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            emailVerification=true;
        }else {
            inputField.setBackground(Color.RED);
            emailVerification=false;
        }
        break;
    case "password":
        if(registerFormVerification.passwordVerification(String.valueOf(inputField.getText()))) {
            inputField.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            passwordVerification =true;
            pass.setText(inputField.getText());
        }else {
            inputField.setBackground(Color.RED);
            passwordVerification = false;
            
        }
        break;
    case "ripetiPassword":
        if(Arrays.equals(pass.getPassword(),inputField.getText().toCharArray())){
            inputField.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            ripPassVerification=true;
            
        }else {
            inputField.setBackground(Color.RED);
            ripPassVerification=false;
            
        }
        break;
    }
    if( nameVerification == true && cognomeVerification== true && emailVerification== true && passwordVerification==true && ripPassVerification == true ) {
        save.setEnabled(true);
    }//here is the problem i need ruoloVerification.
}
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    JComboBox field=(JComboBox)e.getSource();
    Object item=field.getSelectedItem();
    
    if(!item.equals("--Seleziona un ruolo--")) {
        ruoloVerification=true;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Side note: "*I used a keylistener for a the textfield..."* -- first of all, don't do this as it can break the functioning of the text component. Instead, use either an ActionListener or DocumentListener or DocumentFilter.

Comment: A related question and answer: [For a large validation task is chain of responsibility pattern a good bet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23408923/for-a-large-validation-task-is-chain-of-responsibility-pattern-a-good-bet)

Comment: Swing is so old now, and HTML 5 is so hot - especially with input verification.

Comment: [*Jakarta Validation*](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/bean-validation/)

Comment: @ControlAltDel: and not to mention JS frameworks such as Vue, React and Svelte and all their associated form handling libraries.

Comment: “I want to validate the fields and if they are ok i want that a button is enabled”  That is not a good user interface design.  A user will not understand what they need to do to enable the submit button.  Instead, leave the button enabled at all times;  if the user presses that button, and any of the fields are not valid, display an error message informing the user of what they need to correct.